# How to make django stop caching templates but not static files?

Tags: django, caching, django-templates, django-pipeline

I am using `django-pipeline` to compress my static files, and using

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'
```

to keep my static files hashed. But the problem is that the template `index.html` that includes all the static files gets cached into the browser, so keeps on including the old files and hence Cache busting doesn't work. How do I solve this problem.

I only want `index.html` to be not cached.

**EDIT:**

Here is my view function

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    if(request.user.id):
        data = request.user.profile()
        return render(request, '<app_name>/index.html', {'data': data})
    else:
        return render(request, '<app_name>/index.html')
```

Comment: How are you serving your files?

Comment: I am serving my static files directly by Nginx. If thats what you mean.?

Comment: what is your view like? do you have caching on that view enabled or maybe you are sending expires header in the view?

Comment: I don't have caching enabled on the view and neither it is sending expire headers. I'll update the question with the view..